# directory structure in Tomcat 5(s)

Tags: java, tomcat

I was wondering if it was possible to maintain a directory structure within the application folder in side `webapps` folder, i.e. I have created a folder called ITC357, which acts as my application folder which carries all my files, so the directory path is as follows:

```
C:/Program Files/Tomcat5/webapps/ITC357
```

I'm doing an assignment and I would like to deploy that `ITC357` in a separate folder can I do this? if so how?

Comment: Are you wanting to use a folder other than webapps to store your deployed applications, or are you wanting to deploy the code contained in ITC357 under a different context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking:

- If you asking if it is possible to have directories inside `C:/Program Files/Tomcat5/webapps/ITC357` then the answer is "Yes".
- If you are asking if it is possible to put your webapps file in a separate directory then the answer is "Inadvisable".  The tomcat framework looks for certain files within the `webapps/<name>` tree; e.g. a `context.xml` file, a `web.xml` file, classes / JARs, etc.  You could code your servlet to look for other things in other places, but this causes various problems with deployment (and undeployment) and security.

If that doesn't cover it, please clarify your question.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for the reply; Sorry for bean confusing, I even confuse myself, anyway it's the first option you've mentioned. What I want is to have separate folders for the user interface part of the site:  C:/Program Files/Tomcat5/ITC357/UI (for example) this will contain all the .html .jsp images etc.

Comment: @Kushan - that will work.  Of course, your servlets, resources, etc need to use the appropriate paths relative to the webapp URL, etc.

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks for that, I was unsure of this

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing JSPs, then the URL of the JSP will include any subdirectories that you create. So if under ITC357 you create a subdirectory called "foo", and in that subdirectory you have a JSP called "bar.jsp", and your context name is "plugh", then the URL of that JSP will be "http://whateverserver.com/plugh/foo/bar.jsp".

If you are using servlets, then it is up to your code to decide what to do with any URLs passed to it. You could map "http://whateverserver.com/plugh/foo/twisty.do" to "c:/program files/tomcat5/webapps/ITC357/WEB-INF/classes/foo/twisty.class", or you could map it to someplace totally different. (I prefer to map to a package name that matches the URL unless there's good reason to do otherwise.)